# Setting up a POST Web API Method?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, rest, asp.net-web-api, azure-mobile-services

I need to set up a Web API Method to accept POST parameters sent from my Android and iOS Client apps. This is what I have now:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/postcomment")]
public IHttpActionResult PostComment([FromBody]string comment, [FromBody]string email, [FromBody]string actid)
{
       string status = CommentClass.PostNewComment(comment, email, actid);
       return Ok(status);
}
```

However this doesn't work since I believe the method cannot take multiple [FromBody] parameters at once? How can I properly set up this method such that it accepts 3 POST parameters from the body of the request?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a model. **DefaultModelBinder** will bind the those values from the **form** to your model.

[image]

[image]

```
public class CommentViewModel
{
    public string Comment { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Actid { get; set; }
}

public IHttpActionResult PostComment([FromBody]CommentViewModel model)
{
    string status = ...;
    return Ok(status);
}
```

Comment: Thank you mate. However, when I'm calling the method from my android and iOS clients, I do not have this custom class there. How can it be compatible even if I create the same model in my android and ios projects?

Comment: You just need to post **JSON** values from client. Please look at the Request Body of the fiddle screenshot. DefaultModelBinder is very smart.

Comment: Hey Win, I get a "{"message":"The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'."}" response. I used the exact same method you used and added a [Route("api/postcomment")] on top of it though

Comment: You need to select POST from dropdownlist (located right under Parser tab).

Comment: Oh WOW you beautiful human being! I was struggling with this all day! THANKS MAN :D

Answer (score 1):

You can do this -

> 1. Create one custom class and add three properties for your three input parameters.
> 2. Change the `PostComment` method to accept only one parameters of that class.
> 3. While calling this WebAPI, create one object of this class, assign values to the properties, serialize it to JSON or XML and POST it.
> 4. The WebAPI will automatically de-serialize your Request Body and pass it to your method.